# A short as possible unique ID

Tags: java, optimization, netbeans

I'm making a tool for optimizing script and now I want to compress all names in it to the minimum.
I got the function started for it, but it somehow bugs and stops after length 2 is exceeded.
Is there an easier way to do this? I just need a pattern that generates a String starting from a -> z then aa -> az ba -> bz and so on.

```
    public String getToken() {
    String result = ""; int i = 0;
    while(i < length){
        result = result + charmap.substring(positions[i], positions[i]+1);
        positions[length]++;
        if (positions[current] >= charmap.length()){
            positions[current] = 0;
            if ( current < 1 ) {
                current++;length++;
            }else{
                int i2 = current-1;
                while( i2 > -1 ){
                    positions[i2]++;
                    if(positions[i2] < charmap.length()){
                        break;
                    }else if( i2 > 0 ){
                        positions[i2] = 0;
                    }else{
                        positions[i2] = 0;
                        length++;current++;
                    }
                    i2--;

                }


            }


        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

UNLIKE THE OTHER QUESTIONS!! I dont just want to increase an integer, the length increases to much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one I used

```
public class AsciiID {
    private static final String alphabet= 
                   "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    private int currentId;

    public String nextId() {
        int id = currentId++;
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            b.append(alphabet.charAt(id % alphabet.length()));
        } while((id /=alphabet.length()) != 0);

        return b.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sigh ok so much for "simple algorithm we won't do it for you but here are some tips"..

Answer (score 1):

I would use a base 36 or base 64 (depending on case sensitivity) library and run it with an integer and before you output, convert the integer to a base 36/64 number. You can think in terms of sequence, which is easier, and the output value is handled by a trusted library.

Comment: What do I need a trusted library for if I just want to add up chars. And how does base64 make small ids.

Comment: Because you're trying to do something that someone else has already handled. And judging by your code so far, you're having trouble with it. So why have trouble with something someone else has done already? :-D Base 36 is like counting, but you go 1,2,3...8,9,a,b,...y,z,10,11..19,1a,1b... So you can do your logic in integer and just output as a base 36.

Comment: Michał Šrajer suggested something like that, how can I implement Uppercase letters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Integer.toString(i++, Character.MAX_RADIX)
```

It's base36. It will be not as greatly compressed as Base64 but you have a 1-line implementation.

Comment: Though that doesn't create a string representation in [a-z] - but then I don't see why that'd be necessary. And if we use ASCII for output  that's not the most efficient representation.

Comment: Pretty much what I want, is there a way to include upper case letters?

Answer (score 0):

You could search for some library that operates numbers of any radix, say 27, 37 or more. Then you output that number as alphanumeric string (like HEX, but with a-zA-Z0-9).

Comment: But I didnt find anything that could me help, thats why I ask for help/an example.

Answer (score 0):

Well let's assume we can only output ASCII (for unicode this problem gets.. complicated): As a quick look shows its printable characters are in the range [32,126]. So to get the most efficient representation of this problem we have to encode a given integer in base 94 so to speak and add 32 to any generated char.

How you do that? Look up how Sun does it in `Integer.toString()` and adapt it accordingly. Well it's probably more complex than necessary - just think about how you convert a number into radix 2 and adapt that. In its simplest form that's basically a loop with one division and modulo.

Comment: I extremely doubt that, because I don't know any charset that's limited to those glyphs.. But well - so you have to implement a base 62 (that also throws base64 out) algorithm and either have some ifs to decide which number maps to which symbol or use a string and charAt(). That's a really simple algorithm, so don't expect us to do it for you.

Comment: If its so simple, why cant I find it anywhere? All base64 Encoders start with 2 or 4 chars from beginning. I wanna start with a single "a" . And I can output "_" but thats it. I have to replace variable names in a scripting language that doesnt allow others.

Comment: It's more than simple enough that if you stop copying code around for a second and start THINKING about the actual problem for one second you could easily adapt your average base64 encoder (though base64 has some additional properties that you don't need) or maybe even implement it yourself..

Answer (score 0):

In your tool you need to create a dictionary, which will contain an unique integer id for each unique string and the string itself. When adding strings to the dictionary you increment given id for each newly added unique string. Once dictionary is completed, you can simply convert ids to `String` using something like this:

```
  static final String CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  static final int CHARS_LENGTH = CHARS.length();

  public String convert(int id) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    do {
      sb.append(CHARS.charAt(id % CHARS_LENGTH));
      id = id / CHARS_LENGTH;
    } while(id != 0);
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This function generates the Nth [Bijective Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) (except zeroth). This is the most optimal coding ever possible. (The zeroth would be an empty string.)

If there were 10 possible characters, `0`-`9`, it generates, in order:

- 10 strings of length **1**, from "0" to "9"
- 10*10 strings of length **2**, from "00" to "99"
- 10*10*10 strings of length **3**, from "000" to "999"
- etc.

The example uses 93 characters, because I just happened to need those for Json.

```
private static final char[] ALLOWED_CHARS =
        " !#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
                .toCharArray();

private static final AtomicInteger uniqueIdCounter = new AtomicInteger();

public static String getToken() {
    int id = uniqueIdCounter.getAndIncrement();
    return toBijectiveNumber(id, ALLOWED_CHARS);
}

public static String toBijectiveNumber(int id, char[] allowedChars) {
    assert id >= 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8);

    int divisor = 1;
    int length  = 1;
    while (id >= divisor * allowedChars.length) {
        divisor *= allowedChars.length;
        length++;

        id -= divisor;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sb.append(allowedChars[(id / divisor) % allowedChars.length]);
        divisor /= allowedChars.length;
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```